# Build a solution with MS build when the solution configuration doesn't match all projects

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, solution

I have a solution which has a configuration, let's call it `A`. 80% of the projects in that solution also have a configuration `A` but the rest do not. Although they do need to be built.

When I build with `msbuild proj.sol /p:Configuration=A /p:Platform=x64` I get error messages like this

```
error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
```

It seams that I can build move of my projects but not the ones where the configuration name does not match the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your solution configuration 'A' to ensure that the other projects have a valid project configuration for solution configuration 'A'

1. In Visual Studio, go to menu Build > Configuration Manager.
2. In the Active Solution Configurations drop down list select configuration 'A'
3. Select a configuration that you want to use for each project. Note it does not have to be     'A'. It can be any valid project configuration.
4. Ensure the platform setting is set for the projects as well. They can be different then the solution platform. I.E. solution x64 but one project might be set to x86.

```
msbuild proj.sln /p:Configuration=A /p:Platform=x64
```

[image: Configuration Manager]

Comment: So in VS when your active configuration is set to A and platform x64 it builds with no errors? Also,  msbuild proj.sol /p:Configuration=A /p:Platform=x64 should be updated to msbuild proj.sln /p:Configuration=A /p:Platform=x64 . What happens if you just run the command msbuild proj.sln?

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the same problem. It was fixed by installing [F# Tools for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=34675) and restart Xamarin as the steps described in [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15774/the-target-build-does-not-exist-in-the-project-error-when-trying-to-compile-f-project)

The bug was filed [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19208)